# Switch QPoint to struct in mathematical expression

Tags: c++, qt

Don't understand how QPoint is being calculated here. QPoint has x and y. I've tried running this with a custom struct but I get errors such as Invalid operands to binary expression.

Works:

```c
void test(QPoint p0, QPoint  p1, QPoint  p2, QPoint  p3) {
    QPoint point;

    for(double t = 0.0; t<=1.0; t+=0.001){
        point = pow((1-t),3) * p0 + 3 * pow((1-t),2) * t * p1 + 3 * (1-t) * pow(t,2) * p2 + pow(t,3) * p3;
    }

}
```

Doesn't work

```c
struct Point {
  int x;
  int y;
};
void test(Point p0, Point p1, Point p2, Point p3) {
    Point point;

    for(double t = 0.0; t<=1.0; t+=0.001){
        point = pow((1-t),3) * p0 + 3 * pow((1-t),2) * t * p1 + 3 * (1-t) * pow(t,2) * p2 + pow(t,3) * p3;
    }

}
```

Can I get this to work somehow using the Point structure instead of QPoint?

Comment: You need to overload the `operator*` for your `Point` to define the multiplication. Obviously `QPoint` has done this.

Comment: Do you want to rebuild QT functionality in C?

Comment: @Gerhardh yes, sorry c++. I want the point struct to work same as QPoint so I am able to calculate this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpoint.html) about `QPoint`, you'll see that the `operator*()` and `operator+()` (that you use here) are overloaded for `QPoint`.

If you want to make it work with your class, you will need to overload them as well.

The minimum required overloads you need to make your `test()` function work are:

```
Point operator*(double factor, const Point & p)
{
    return Point{
                 static_cast<int>(std::round(p.x * factor)),
                 static_cast<int>(std::round(p.y * factor))
                };
}

Point operator+(const Point & p1, const Point & p2)
{
    return Point{p1.x + p2.x, p1.y + p2.y};
}
```

For more consistency, you could add the symetric:

```
Point operator*(const Point & p, double factor)
{
    return factor * p;
}
```

Anyway, if you want to replace `QPoint` with `Point` with full arithmetic compatibility, I would recommend you to write all the overloads (for arithmetic comparison) listed in the documentation of `QPoint`.

Comment: I tried to copy this but I am getting `overloaded 'operator*` must be unary or binary operator(has 3 parameters)

Comment: @squnk Then you didn't copy properly :) The overloads I provided are binary (as you can see, they have only two parameters).

Comment: @squnk I wrote an [example here](https://godbolt.org/z/TYPz4nq3s) of the code above, I can't do more :)